# How to create horizontal scroll bar in the web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to create horizontal scroll bar in the web page?. I dont have anything in the webpage, but i want to create horizontal scroll bar in the web page, not with the div.?

Comment: `body {overflow-x: scroll}` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code in css:

```
body{
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

or

```
body{
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```